# Como recuperar a quantidade de mensagens em uma fila do RabbitMQ?

Tags: java

Alguém aqui ja trabalhou com o rabbitmq implementando java para envio de mensagens? Preciso de uma ajuda de vocês.

Preciso recuperar a quantidade de mensagens em uma fila no RabbitMQ. Esta é a minha classe, é uma tarefa, na qual fica consumindo as mensagens:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    ProtocolInternalMessageFacade protocolInternalFacade = new ProtocolInternalMessageFacade();

    while (true) {
        try {
            if (CheckServer.hostAvailabilityCheck()) {
                /* 
                 * quando eu passo o mouse em cima desse queueingConsumer,
                 * é ai que me mostra a propriedade size, se por exemplo estiver 2
                 * mensagens nessa propriedade, mostra Size = 2
                 */
                QueueingConsumer queueingConsumer = Consumer.getQueueingConsumer(QUEUE_NAME);
                QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = null;

                try {
                    QueueingConsumer.Delivery deliveryTmp;

                    /* 
                     * aqui eu fiz o seguinte: por exemplo coloquei um for de um a
                     * 5(por isso eu queria essa quantidade de mensagem que tem nessa
                     * fila, para que fazer esse for de acordo com essa quantidade.)
                     * Se eu estiver por exemplo 2 registros, ele sempre irá pegar
                     * esse ultimo registro, salvar e mostrar para mim.
                     */
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                        deliveryTmp = queueingConsumer.nextDelivery(5);

                        if(deliveryTmp != null){
                            delivery = deliveryTmp;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException | ShutdownSignalException |
                            ConsumerCancelledException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    LOGGER.trace(ConvertStackTrace.getStringFromStackTrace(e));
                }

                if (delivery != null) {
                    ProtocolInternalMessage protocolInternalMessage = 
                            (ProtocolInternalMessage) ConvertData.fromBytes(delivery.getBody());
                    protocolInternalFacade.insert(protocolInternalMessage);
                }

                Consumer.getChannel().close();
                Consumer.getConnection().close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Server Not Found. Please, contact the administrator");
                LOGGER.error("Error connect server");
            }

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ShutdownSignalException | 
                    ConsumerCancelledException | ServiceException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            LOGGER.trace(ConvertStackTrace.getStringFromStackTrace(e));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: E qual é a ajuda que você precisa?

Comment: preciso saber se tem como eu pegar a quantidade de mensagem que vem nessa fila.. por exemplo: mandei duas mensagens, quero pegar essa quantidade no client .

Comment: É possivel fazer isso?

Comment: Você consegue saber a quantidade de mensagens que estão na fila, veja [`DeclareOk`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.5.1/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.5.1/com/rabbitmq/client/AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk.html). É isto mesmo?

Comment: Então, eu tenho esse codigo abaixo, onde no meu queueingConsumer tem um size quando eu debugo.. Eu queria pegar essa quantidade.

Comment: QueueingConsumer queueingConsumer = Consumer.getQueueingConsumer(QUEUE_NAME);
                    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = null;

Comment: Esse size tá em qual objeto, nas propriedades? Fica difícil ajudar sem saber detalhes, considere editar sua pergunta com o seu cenário, o que você já tentou, observações que ache relevante para quem for lhe ajudar, algo que torne possível reproduzir e propor uma solução a você. Veja [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Editei minha pergunta..Coloquei o codigo, talvez fique mais claro agora.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23193/discussion-between-ivan-martineli-and-bruno-cesar).